# How to tell the compiler to optimize array access?

Tags: c++

I have the following fragment of code. It contains 3 sections where I measure memory access runtime. First is plain iteration over the array. The second is almost the same with the exception that the array address received from the function call. The third is the same as the second but manually optimized.

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

std::map<void*, void*> cache;

constexpr int elems = 1000000;
double x[elems] = {};

template <typename T>
T& find_in_cache(T& var) {
    void* key = &var;
    void* value = nullptr;
    if (cache.count(key)) {
        value = cache[key];
    } else {
        value = malloc(sizeof(T));
        cache[key] = value;
    }
    return *(T*)value;
}

int main() {
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds1, elapsed_seconds2, elapsed_seconds3;

    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) { // account for cache effects
        // first section
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 1; i < elems; i++) {
            x[i] = (x[i-1] + 1.0) * 1.001;
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed_seconds1 = end-start;

        // second section
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 1; i < elems; i++) {
            find_in_cache(x)[i] = (find_in_cache(x)[i-1] + 1.0) * 1.001;
        }
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed_seconds2 = end-start;

        // third section
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        double* y = find_in_cache(x);
        for (int i = 1; i < elems; i++) {
            y[i] = (y[i-1] + 1.0) * 1.001;
        }
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed_seconds3 = end-start;
    }
    std::cout << "elapsed time 1: " << elapsed_seconds1.count() << "s\n";
    std::cout << "elapsed time 2: " << elapsed_seconds2.count() << "s\n";
    std::cout << "elapsed time 3: " << elapsed_seconds3.count() << "s\n";

    return x[elems - 1]; // prevent optimizing away
}
```

The timings of these sections are following:

```
elapsed time 1: 0.0018678s
elapsed time 2: 0.00423903s
elapsed time 3: 0.00189678s
```

Is it possible to change the interface of `find_in_cache()` without changing the body of the second iteration section to make its performance the same as section 3?

Comment: how are you testing this? How are you compiling this?

Comment: @JHBonarius `g++ test.cpp -O3 && ./a.out`

Comment: You could lie with `[[gnu::pure]]`.

Comment: your workload is too little for the measured times be meaningful. You should increase number of iterations, measure many times and take the average (or consider worst case, there are different strategies)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 why is that? I am pretty confident in these times and they show what I expect: the second section is slower because the compiler can't optimize function call away from loop.

Comment: why are you using `malloc`? And are you aware of the memory leak?

Comment: @MarcGlisse `[[gnu::pure]]` helped a bit, it reduced runtime from `0.0042` to `0.0030`.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I am aware. This code supposed to do more than that, but it is irrelevant for the purpose of the question, so I tried to shorten it like that.

Comment: one issue is that measurements always come with "noise". Statistically the influence of noise is reduced when you take more samples and average them. Strictly speaking the variance of a single measurement is infinite and its not possible to use it to conclude on the real distribution of time it takes to run the program

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 True. I just hope that for such simple hacking of this code I can avoid doing everything properly (I run it multiple times and the result seems consistent).

Comment: With clang, `[[gnu::const]]` gives you the performance you want. Gcc seems to have a harder time pulling it out of the loop (I tried with `[[gnu::const,gnu::noinline]]` to make sure the attribute was not lost), maybe worth a bug report.

Comment: @MarcGlisse That works nicely for clang, thanks. If you post it as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
template <typename T>
[[gnu::const]]
T& find_in_cache(T& var) { ... }
```

lets clang optimize the code the way you want, but gcc fails to handle the call as a loop invariant, even with `gnu::noinline` to make sure the attribute is not lost (maybe worth a bug report?).

How safe such code is may depend on the rest of your code. It is a lie since the function can use memory, but it may be ok if that memory is private enough to the function. Preventing inlining of `find_in_cache` may help reduce the risks.

You can also convince gcc to optimize with

```cpp
template <typename T>
[[gnu::const,gnu::noinline]]
T& find_in_cache(T& var) noexcept { ... }
```

which would cause your program to terminate if there isn't enough memory to add an element in the cache.

Comment: quite strange to see that clang supports gcc annotations better than gcc itself, would be nice to find workaround for gcc as well.